# grep: operation not supported on socket

Tags: sockets, cygwin, grep

I get this error on cygwin 1.7.5-1 under zsh and rxvt when I try to run

```
grep "getDirectories" *
```

It seems to happen once per directory.

I successfully ran this operation many times under cygwin 1.7.1 just a few days ago before I had to get a new laptop.  Anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: No idea, but you might want to ask on the Cygwin mailing list. You'll need to provide more details though, in particular what sort of directories this happens in.

Comment: I would first check what `*` expands to. Perhaps you have soft link to some socket? Do a `ls -ld *` and check manually, whether all entries you see make sense for a `grep` command.

Answer (score 0):

What is your current directory when you execute your grep command?

If it is / or /tmp then may be you are trying to perform grep command on some unix-type socket file, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem went away after a reboot, but it existed consistently for a few days with some versions of cygwin.  This error seemed to happen once per directory, on a regular NTFS file system, under Windows XP + Cygwin (i.e. no real unix sockets available).

No answer because problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but using the bash script in one of remote repositories. For me it worked after removing the repository and cloning it again. Would probably work with just removing the script itself if it is locally on your machine.